# How to detect braces and comma regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Image a really long json string.

I want to detect this part with a regular expression:

```
},
 {
  "@context"
```

This is the expression I got so far, but I got two results, not only one. The only difference are the braces with the comma before the opening braces.

```
var matches = data.match(/({\"@context.*)/);
```

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot get "two results" (meaning "two matches") with a `match` and a regex having no `g` flag. More, you [can't get any results](https://regex101.com/r/bF6F4t/1) here at all, since there is no match. Show your real test case please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works `/\},[\s\S]*?\{[\s\S]*?"@context"/g` you can also try your regex https://regexr.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).